# Unit test with mocking repository fails

Tags: spring, mocking, put

I am trying to write unit test for my method:

```
public OffenceEntity put(String id, OffenceUpdateRequestModel offenceRequestModel) {
    OffenceEntity offenceEntity = getById(id);
    if (!offenceRequestModel.getName().equals(offenceEntity.getName())) {
        if (offenceEntityRepository.existsByName(offenceRequestModel.getName())) {
            throw new ValueAlreadyExistsException(offenceRequestModel.getName());
        }
    }
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(offenceRequestModel, offenceEntity);
    return offenceEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(offenceEntity);
}
```

getById will return object from database or will throw custom exception. Additionally in if I am checking if there is already object with the same name.
And next I want to write unit test with mock:

```
@Test
public void putWorks() {
    //given
    String offenceID = "00000000000000000000000000000002";
    OffenceUpdateRequestModel offenceUpdateRequestModel = new OffenceUpdateRequestModel(
            "Speed limit 40km/h", 8, 8000);

    OffenceEntity offenceEntityFromDB = new OffenceEntity("00000000000000000000000000000002",
            "Speed limit 20km/h", 4, 4000, Set.of(), true);

    Mockito.when(offenceEntityRepository.findById(offenceID)).thenReturn(
            Optional.of(offenceEntityFromDB));
    Mockito.when(offenceService.getById(offenceID)).thenReturn(offenceEntityFromDB);
    OffenceEntity result = offenceService.put(offenceID, offenceUpdateRequestModel);

    //then
    assertEquals(result.getName(), offenceUpdateRequestModel.getName());
    assertEquals(result.getAmountOfFine(), offenceUpdateRequestModel.getAmountOfFine(), 0.0);
    assertEquals(result.getPenaltyPoints(), offenceUpdateRequestModel.getPenaltyPoints());
}
```

but test fail with error and other tests with mocking methods from repository works:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
OffenceEntity cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

**EDIT:**
I will add getByID method from a service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DriverService {
    private final DriverEntityRepository driverEntityRepository;

    public DriverEntity getById(String id) {
        return driverEntityRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow((() -> new ValueNotFoundException(id)));
    }

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DriverServiceUnitTests {
    @Autowired
    private DriverService driverService;

    @MockBean
    private DriverEntityRepository driverEntityRepository;
```

Comment: where is the method "findById" in the service?

Comment: I think the service is not a mock class, so you cannot stubb the service.getById
you should define the method again. not to return 'OffenceEntity'

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your question. As not all the code of the class you're testing and its dependencies is present in the question, I'm assuming you're mocking a method on the class you're testing on line:
`Mockito.when(offenceService.getById(offenceID)).thenReturn(offenceEntityFromDB);`

This should not be possible, so that's one issue. Could you post the dependencies of your `Service` class and the method `getById` as well?

Comment: do you have information on which line of code the issue happens on? The error clearly states that the mock is returning a wrong type instead of an Optional..

Comment: Yes, in line with: Mockito.when(offenceService.getById(offenceID)).thenReturn(offenceEntityFromDB); with message: 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
OffenceEntity cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional'

Comment: that is then not mocked correctly. You are testing the method `put` from the `OffenceService`. But you're also trying to mock a method of your service. Try to mock the method `findById()` from your `EntityRepository` mock with the correct parameters. Otherwise debug the test and stop at the method that returns the wrong type.